# rails destroy devise:views not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to delete views that were made by Devise and I want to forbid users to access the pages that were made by one.

I tried to run `rails destroy devise:views`. It didn't work and I don't know/can't figure out how to delete view created by Devise

```
  invoke  Devise::Generators::SharedViewsGenerator
  remove    app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb
  invoke  form_for
  remove    app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb
  invoke  erb
  remove    app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/mailer/email_changed.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/mailer/password_change.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
  remove    app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `rails destroy devise:views Model`
or delete the `views/devise` folder manually.

Comment: I have already deleted the view files that were made by devise manually.